# Xcode Capabilities lacking Push Notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I was following a tutorial of how to add Push Notifications to an iOS app, but I got stuff near the end. It asked to turn on Push Notifications in Capabilities, but I don't have that option. Please let me know how to fix this problem, thank you.

P.S. I am enrolled in the development program and I pretty sure that the app was not a Wildcard app, because I started a new app.

Thanks!

[These are the options I have, lacking Push Notifications,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHzIP.png)

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I am using Xcode 6.4

Comment: The `Push Notification` option was added in Xcode 7. As far as I'm aware, you don't need it enabled (as Push worked fine before Xcode 7)